# How to copy an angular $ function from one object to another

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I have a controller ctrl which has `ctrl.$setValidity()` method. I am doing `angular.copy(ctrl,ctrlCopy)` and I trying to access `ctrlCopy.$setValidity()` but I got error:

> $setValidity is not a function.

I wonder why `angular.copy` doesn't copy all the $function from an object to another.

Comment: Can you add the code of the controller ?

Comment: I have created this jsfiddle.net/j3u1xed2 which I need the isolated form does its own validation and not propagates to the parent form. as you may know $setValidity is a function from angular library. and using the new version of angular library (v1.6.4) I can't copy this function from 1 object to another. 0pen the developer tool, you will see there's an error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `angular.copy()` a controller... period.
If you want to share a function then create a service that returns the function and inject the service into the two separate controllers

Comment: I have created this http://jsfiddle.net/j3u1xed2/ which I need the isolated form does its own validation and not propagates to the parent form. as you may know $setValidity is a function from angular library. So how could you create a service and inject it in this scenario?